# How to view a markdown file in jupyter lab properly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

How to view a markdown file in Jupyter lab properly?

The readme file of a git project is written in markdown, as usual. How can one properly view it in Jupyter lab (rendered)? Currently I see the text version only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A good solution is shown here in the
[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQsRlqK-z1c&ab_channel=Jupyter%2FIPython)

Open the file, right click on the content, "Show markdown preview"
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the open markdown text editor area and you should get a menu option "Show markdown preview".  Select that and it will render the text into markdown in another window (side by side by default)